# What do I need to do to get Onepage to stop validating the CC number I'm entering?

Tags: onepage-checkout

I've setup a new instance of our development server on localhost, checked out the latest working copy, and was given a copy of a database backup to use with it. After getting all of this setup and working, I went through a demo transaction to make sure my checkout was working after reverting to the working copy.

It looks as though the checkout is actually trying to process my transaction on the development server now though, as it's declining the card with:

```
Error Code: 10544: Please use another payment card
```

I've set the `System->Configuration->Payment Methods->Authorize.Net->Test` to yes, but it's still trying to process my card it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each payment gateway vendor has their own approach to facilitate test transactions. In the current case. IIRC Authorize.net has settings at both the external (i.e. originating or Magento) end and the internal (the actual Authorize.net account) end. There are also credit card numbers and amounts which may trigger specific responses from the gateway. Additionally, there is the [Luhn check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm#Calculation_of_the_check_digit) which is often performed client-side to validate the account number, so gateway test cards will have to meet these criteria as well

A test card which can be used for Authorize.net is Visa 4111111111111111 with any CCV and an expiry in the future.

Comment: For this specific test case, 4111111111111111 is the card that is being declined. It's definitely passing the Luhn check, I suppose what I'm going to have to look into is the internal (Authorize.net) area of this particular problem.

Comment: If you are trying to test things which just require a successful transaction, you can use the Saved CC module. It goes without saying that using this module in production is a Really Bad Idea®.